# Please merge the "child" tag into the "children" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-wikis

Since the beginning we decided here on plural tags (with some caveats).

Also tag wikis should not be definitions of common words, they should describe the kids of questions the tag is intended for. I'm pretty sure more than half of us know what "child" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All done. Thanks for bringing this up. I think we should revamp the good old seasonal tag handling post we used to have.